# how to show pictures by radio button list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have a project that I want show one record from DB by radio button list.and after selecting one option and click on Next button next record loads.this is my Html code :

```
<table style ="width :800px">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/stdents12.jpeg" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px">


                <table style="width: 950px" id="TABLE1" onclick="return TABLE1_onclick()">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8" style="color: white; height: 21px; background-color: #3366ff">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Test No :" Width="82px"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="TestNo" runat="server" Text="Label" Width="100px"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Test Name :" Width="84px"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="TestName" runat="server" Text="Name Of the Test" Width="501px"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Question :"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="Question" runat="server" Text="N of T" Width="52px"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 23px" rowspan="5">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 1px;">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 1px;">  



            </td>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 1px;">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 1px;">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 1px;">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 1px;">
                </td>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 1px;">
             <div class="timerCss"> <asp:Label ID="lblTimerCount" runat="server" Height="5px" Width="232px"></asp:Label>&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7" align="right">
                <asp:Image ID="Image2"  runat="server" />
                <asp:Label ID="Questionlbl" runat="server" Height="66px" Text="Label" 
                    Width="317px"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">


                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                </asp:RadioButtonList>


                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 12px;">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 12px;">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 12px;">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 12px;">
                </td>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 12px;">
                </td>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 12px;">
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server"   Text="Skip" Width="55px" /></td>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 12px;">
                <asp:Button ID="BtnNext" runat="server" onclick="BtnNext_Click" Text="Next" 
                    Width="70px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: silver;" class="style1">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and this is my code behind page:

```
void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OnlineExamEntities context = new OnlineExamEntities();
        StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();
        bldr.AppendFormat("var Timer = new myTimer({0},{1},'{2}','timerData');", this.timerStartValue, this.TimerInterval, this.lblTimerCount.ClientID);
        bldr.Append("Timer.go()");
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "TimerScript", bldr.ToString(), true);
        ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("timerData", timerStartValue.ToString());
        /////////////////////////////
        List<int> a = (List<int>)Session["QnumList"];
        List<string> resulttemp = new List<string>();

        int j = a[Convert.ToInt32(Session["Click"].ToString())];

        var q3 = ((from c in context.questions
                   orderby c.QID
                   where c.QID == j
                   select c)).SingleOrDefault();
        resulttemp.Add(q3.trueAns.ToString());
        Session["result"] = resulttemp;

        Questionlbl.Text = q3.Question1.ToString();
        Image2.ImageUrl = q3.ans4.ToString();
        RadioButtonList1.Items.Clear();
        string ans1, ans2, ans3;
        ans1 = q3.ans1.ToString();
        ans2 = q3.ans2.ToString();
        ans3 = q3.ans3.ToString();
        RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(String.Format("<img src='{0}'>", ans1));
        RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(String.Format("<img src='{0}'>", ans2));
        RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(String.Format("<img src='{0}'>", ans3));

    }
```

and when I choose one option and click Next button to load another record I get this error :

***A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (RadioButtonList1="***

I adjusted Validate Request ="false" but it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server is warning you that someone might insert an Html code For example if you want to get FirstName but someone writes inside: "alert('Haha')", then when you will display the data entered you might see an alert box. It is not a good thing to cancel validation. You can use [Server.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx) for that:

```
RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(Server.HtmlEncode(String.Format("<img src='{0}'>", ans1)));
```

And after the user selects a value then you can decode that with [Server.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke).

**However**, in this case you just need the chosen img, not the whole `img` tag, so you can set the value differently (second param is the value):

```
RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(String.Format("<img src='{0}'>", ans1), ans1));
```

This way the html form will hold only the image path which is not considered a potentially dangerous value.